# REST: Creating a Json based Query: Which http method to use?

Tags: json, rest, http

I have a question to RESTful services. In REST the POST method is used to create an entity.
And GET is used to query entities. Right?

As I read in another posts it is not allowed in HTTP to send a GET request with a body. 
But when I want to send Json to make a query, what is the best way? Are there any best practices or how do you solve such json queries?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: You are looking for query params

Comment: No, currently not :) I want to send json to the server. And the question was what's the best way. If to use GET or POST or whatever. But VoiceOfUnreason described it very well and the linked article is interesting. It seems that the best way is to send it via a POST request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In REST the POST method is used to create an entity. And GET is used to query entities. Right?

Not really.  [GET](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) is used to fetch representations of [resources](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1).  [POST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) is deliberately vague -- anything [not worth standardizing](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post) can use POST.

> when I want to send Json to make a query, what is the best way?

There is no best way to do it, just trade offs.

The basic plot of HTTP is that you GET representations of resources.  If the resource you want doesn't exist, you create a new one.  So the "REST" flow would look something like sending a request to the server to create a "the answer to my query" resource, and then using GET to obtain the current representation of that resource.  Which is great, because we can fetch the latest representation of that resource any time we're worried that our copy is out of date.  Other people with the same query can use the same resource, so we can use a general-purpose cache to take a lot of the work.  The end result is "web scale".

OK, not that great, because we learned that sending information over insecure channels is a bad idea; but we can put a general-purpose caching proxy in front of our server, and get some scale that way.

But "create a new resource" is a lot of ceremony when you only expect to need the query once.

Creating a new resource was using POST in this situation anyway, so why not return a representation of the solution right away?  And the answer is, go right ahead!  that works great... but doesn't give you any cache support at all.  You are effectively performing a remote call under the guise of modifying a resource.

Also, POST doesn't promise idempotent semantics -- on an unreliable network, requests can get lost, and general purpose components won't know that *in this particular case* it is harmless to just repeat the same request.

PUT has idempotent semantics... but it also has very specific opinions about the contents of the payload that don't match "query" at all.

You can dig through other [standardized methods](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml), but there aren't really any good fits.  The only methods that are close are SEARCH and REPORT, which are coupled to WebDAV semantics.

You can invent your own non standard method; but general purpose components won't understand it.

You can standardize a new method with the semantics you need, but that's a lot of work.

Or you can [just use POST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post).

Remember, the web took over the world using nothing more than GET and POST.  So it's probably fine.